# IIS Application Pool Recycle - CLR Crash

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, application-pool

We are using IIS 7 , one of the application which has 27 sites.
It is set to recycle every 29 hours.
After each recycle there is a alert of CLR crash (app dynamics).

After 3-4 alerts everythings work fine.

From Event logs:
A process serving application pool 'en.au.netgear.com' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '8904'. The data field contains the error number.
Event ID: 5011

Comment: The crash dump should tell a lot about what's up. So please work with AppDynamics support team.

Comment: What error message did you see in application event log instead of system event? The event indicate that IIS recycle operation crash with app dynamics. So you may need to either analyze dump for inner exception or involve app dynamic team for help.